# Call method on all members of IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I've been playing around with some c# extensions lately and I have a question. I made a 'ForEach' extension for IEnumerables (List has one from Linq, though none exists for IEnumerables.) It's a very simple one:

```
public static void ForEach<T> (this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (T element in source) {
        action(element);
    }
}
```

And you call it like `MyArray.ForEach(element=>element.ElementMethod());`

Though now I was wondering, can I take it one step further and make it something like: `MyArray.ForEach(ElementMethod);`?

Edit: Already some interesting answers, though I was trying something like this:

```
public static void CallOnEach<T> (this IEnumerable<T> source, Action action)
{
    foreach (T element in source) {
        element.action();
    }
}
```

Of course the compiler can't know that 'action' is a method of T, so this doesn't work :( Perhaps there's a way to ensure the compiler of this? Something like `public static void CallOnEach<T> (this IEnumerable<T> source, Action action) where action isFunctionOf T`

Thanks!

Comment: IMHO the lambda is better than what you'd have to do to get your other options to work.

Comment: @juharr You're probably right, though I'm just interested in knowing how far you can go with those extensions methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ElementMethod` is of type `Action<T>` you can use it right now with your extension. And it is the same like `static void` method of type `T`:

```
public static void ElementMethod<T>(T parameter){}

//or

public static void ElementMethod(MyElement element){}
```

*But there is no way how to make it more generic. You can't call some method on your element without reference to it.*

*IMHO: There is no big deal. You are saving just few characters.*

```
MyArray.ForEach(e=>e.ElementMethod());
MyArray.ForEach(ElementMethod);1234567 - // characters saved ;-)
```

Comment: From the example code, it's pretty clear it's an instance method, not an `Action`.

Comment: Of course. But I have described the only way how you can call like `MyArray.ForEach(ElementMethod);`. See my update.

Comment: Technically 'ElementMethod' just has to be a static method that takes a 'T' parameter and returns 'void'

Comment: @juharr good point, I have been just about adding it to my answer

Comment: It's true it's not a big deal, I was just wondering :P Extensions look so cool, and was just interested in how far I could take it :D

Answer (score 1):

You can make ElementMethod an extension method and you would be able to do the Latter

Comment: But only for a specific `ElementMethod`, and each such method would need its own extension method. To do that generically would need some kind of code generation/templating.

Comment: Yea but then it wouldn't work for just any method of the element in the array (unless I make an extension method for every method of the element, which could be a solution but seems a bit useless I think.)

Comment: No thats not entirely true, the same way your foreach statement works on Ienumerable would be the same way your method would work on the collection. When you say methods on the array are you refering to methods that return IEnumerable??